# selecting dynamic class names generated by react from a user script?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I tend to write my own user scripts (aka [Violentmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/) / [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) scripts; formerly Greasemonkey scripts). I often end up selecting elements by class name while doing so - either using native javascript or having the script load jQuery and using that.

I've noticed that sometimes I see dynamically generated class names like "SeriesIndexFooter-footer-**3WmRg**" with the bolded bits appearing to be some randomly generated part (I think this gets generated by React? I haven't used React myself but have sometimes seen "React" in other element names when encountering these). Obviously, I can just hard-code these classnames in my script AS-IS and it will work... but my concern is that if a site / local server app gets updated later that this will break my user script.

e.g.

```
// @run-at      document-end
var footer = document.querySelectorAll('.SeriesIndexFooter-footer-3WmRg');
 
//OR
// @run-at      document-end
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js
var footer = jQuery('.SeriesIndexFooter-footer-3WmRg');
```

Is there a better solution that doesn't rely on hard-coding or avoiding class names entirely but also reduces the risk that my script will break because the random portion of the class name changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can predict class suffix that you are talking about.

That is used for purpose of encapsulating styles so that it applies only for that specific element or group of elements.

What you can do in your case is to use few CSS selectors that relay on searching values in attributes.
In your case it would look something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class*=SeriesIndexFooter-footer]')
```

If you need to be more specific you can chain selectors. For example you can target a type of element `div`. There is no limit in chaining selectors to be more precise in selecting what you need.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=SeriesIndexFooter-footer]')
```

With this line you will select all elements where `class` attribute has a sub-string `"SeriesIndexFooter-footer"` and is `div`. 
[Here is W3Schools doc for that](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

You can find more selectors that suite your cases on [W3Schools doc here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Other word searching CSS selectors that you can use are:

```
[attribute=value]   [target=_blank] Selects all elements with target="_blank"
[attribute~=value]  [title~=flower] Selects all elements with a title attribute containing the word "flower"
[attribute|=value]  [lang|=en]  Selects all elements with a lang attribute value equal to "en" or starting with "en-"
[attribute^=value]  a[href^="https"]    Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value begins with "https"
[attribute$=value]  a[href$=".pdf"] Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value ends with ".pdf"
[attribute*=value]  a[href*="w3schools"]    Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"
```

Comment: awesome; appreciate the quick response! I've used `a[href*="/some/pattern"]` plenty of times, but didn't realize that this syntax supported class names as well.

Comment: Yep, you can get any attribute (even custom ones). By combining them you can narrow down what you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: I will mention for the sake of any others who try this approach that it only considers the entire class attribute. In other words if the element has `<a class="foo-123 bar-456 bat-789">` then using `a[class^="bat"]` does not seem to work as it's in the middle of the attribute string. makes sense when you think about it but if you are used to jQuery and are thinking that `^=` will match beginning of a class *name*, you might be surprised. `a[class*="bat"]` seems to work but I could see situations where precise matching with this approach might be challenging. Still, works great for my purposes.

Comment: Exactly. `^=` will not work for sure. The `*=` covers most of the cases. Although when using that, it could match multiple elements and than you can try and search by tag name or by some specific other attribute.